# Azure connect MS defender to Logic app using terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm

I am trying to connect the MS Defender for Cloud to a logic app which will post the alerts to an URL. I could do the manual setup without any issue but I am struggling to find the appropriate terraform resources to do it in IaC way.
Here is the current setup:

```
resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "logic-app" {
  location            = var.location
  name                = "logic-app-from-tf"
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_action_http" "action" {
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.logic-app.id
  method       = "POST"
  name         = "alert-action"
  uri          = "<URL>"
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_trigger_custom" "trigger" {
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.logic-app.id
  name         = "When_an_Microsoft_Defender_for_Cloud_Alert_is_created_or_triggered"
  body         = jsonencode(
    {
      "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook",
      "inputs": {
        "host": {
          "connection": {
            "referenceName": "ascalert"
          }
        },
        "body": {
          "callback_url": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
        },
        "path": "/Microsoft.Security/Alert/subscribe"
      }
    }
  )
}

resource "azurerm_security_center_automation" "workflow-automation" {
  name                = "workflow-from-tf"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name


  action {
    trigger_url = "<URL>"
    resource_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.logic-app.id
    type        = "logicapp"
  }

  source {
    event_source = "Alerts"
    rule_set {
      rule {
        # this part also not working idk why ... 
        property_path  = "properties.metadata.severity"
        operator       = "Equals"
        expected_value = "High"
        property_type  = "String"
      }
    }
  }

  scopes = ["/subscriptions/${var.subscription_id}"]
}
```

This created the logic app, it also creates the workflow automation in the MS Defender but it fails to create the logic app workflow in the designer.
I compared the generated code both from the manual setup and the terraform setup and here is what I found:

```
{
  "definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
      "alert-action": {
        "type": "Http",
        "inputs": {
          "uri": "<url>",
          "method": "POST",
          "headers": {},
          "queries": {}
        },
        "runAfter": {}
      }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "triggers": {
      "When_a_Microsoft_Defender_for_Cloud_alert_is_created_or_triggered": {
        "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook",
        "inputs": {
          "host": {
            "connection": {
              "referenceName": "ascalert"
            }
          },
          "body": {
            "callback_url": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
          },
          "path": "/Microsoft.Security/Alert/subscribe"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  # This block is empty in the terraform generated code
  "connectionReferences": {
    "ascalert": {
      "api": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/<sub_id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/ascalert"
      },
      "connection": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/<sub-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/ascalert"
      },
      "connectionName": "ascalert"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

So the `connectionReferences` block is empty in the terraform generated code. I tried using the following resource but it did not change anything the block remains still empty.

```
resource "azurerm_api_connection" "connection" {
  managed_api_id      = "/subscriptions/<sub_id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/ascalert"
  name                = "ascalert"
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Which resource should I use to have the `connectionReferences`?

I am using terraform 1.2.4
and azurerm provider 3.29.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in a github bug https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/21120

For me the following changes are working:

```
resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "logic-app" {
  location            = var.location
  name                = "logic-app-from-tf"
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name

  workflow_parameters = {
    "$connections" = jsonencode(
      {
        defaultValue = {}
        type         = "Object"
      }
    )
  }

  parameters = {
    "$connections" = jsonencode({
      "ascalert": {
        "connectionId"   = <connection_id>
        "connectionName" = ascaler
        "id"             = <id>
      } 
    })
  }
}
```

This created the missing connection then the workflow was working as the manually created one.